# Items: Get item revision difference returns empty array

Tags: podio

I am trying to return the diffence in field values between two revisions using app authentication but I'm getting an empty array. 
And when trying to use the api function "Get Item revision" I'm getting "Object not found" response.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

```
const podio = new Podio({
authType: 'app',
clientId: clientId,
clientSecret: clientSecret });
podio.authenticateWithApp(app_id, appToken, (err) => {
if (err) throw new Error(err);

podio.isAuthenticated().then(function () {
// ready to make API calls

apiRoutes.get('/item', function (req, res) {
  podio.request('GET', `/item/702620400/revision/1899410196/1910867632`).then(function (responseData) {
      res.json(responseData);
    });
  });


}).catch(err => res.send(err));
});
```

Comment: Any code samples with exact requests/responses?

Comment: @Pavlo-Podio I have included the code, the response from making this call is '[ ]', I'ts worth mentioning that I have also tried the sandbox environment and I get the same response. Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you also share results from https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/get-item-revision-22373 call for both revisions in question? (1899410196 and 1910867632) ? You might have 2 changes to same field which gives exactly same result so revision diff is empty. E.g. category field changed from 'Open' to 'Closed' and then changed again from 'Closed' to 'Open'. Revision diff will be empty then.

Comment: The field I was modifying had a numeric value which I only incremented, I have made more changes to my item and it seems it can give me the difference between 2 revisions now. And when I'm trying to call the API with "GET /item/{item_id}/revision/{revision}" it still returns "Object not found"

Comment: Apparently whenever I modify a "category" I can see the changes between the 2 revisions, but if I only modify a "number" I won't be able to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podio documentation is not clear enough when describes calls for item revisions. Here is how it works, example in **Ruby**:

```
  item_revisions = Podio::ItemRevision.find_all_by_item_id(item_id)
  last = item_revisions.length - 1
  revision_last = Podio::ItemRevision.find(item_id, last)
  revision_beforelast = Podio::ItemRevision.find(item_id, last - 1)
  diff = Podio::ItemDiff.find_by_item_and_revisions(item_id, last - 1, last)
```

Misleading part is `revision_id` vs `revision` vs `item_revision_id`. 
For "Get Item revision" and "Get item revision difference" calls please use `revision` which goes for each item from 0 and increases by 1 with each new revision. Last revision available for item is `item_revisions.length - 1` from example above.

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue, I was using `item_revision_id` when I should have used `revision`